# Exchange pawns (sliding block puzzle)

Tags: sliding-blocks

How many moves are needed to exchange the positions of black and white pawns? That is, all black pawns should be located at the below line and vice versa. But, all black pawns are identical and so are all white pawns.

Each pawn can be moved to an adjacent blank square.

[image]

Comment: Normal chess rules don't apply?

Comment: @ACB No. Each pawn moves just four direction: up, down, left, right.

Comment: If the two blank spaces are together and a pawn moves two steps at once, does that count as one move or two?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I would count it as two moves because it is natural and convenient for computer programming. Of course, someone may prefer one move.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used a computer to find an optimal solution.

> 52 moves.
>
> ```
>  52 BBBBB    39 BBB.W    26 BBW.W    13 B.WWW
>     X.X.X       XBX.X       XBXWX       X.XWX
>     WWWWW       WBWWW       B.WBW       BBBWB
>
>  51 B.BBB    38 BBB.W    25 BBWWW    12 .BWWW
>     XBX.X       XBXWX       XBX.X       X.XWX
>     WWWWW       WBW.W       B.WBW       BBBWB
>
>  50 BB.BB    37 BBBWW    24 BBWWW    11 ..WWW
>     XBX.X       XBX.X       XBX.X       XBXWX
>     WWWWW       WBW.W       BW.BW       BBBWB
>
>  49 BBB.B    36 BBBWW    23 BBWWW    10 .W.WW
>     XBX.X       XBX.X       XBX.X       XBXWX
>     WWWWW       WB.WW       BWB.W       BBBWB
>
>  48 BBBB.    35 BBBWW    22 BBWWW    9  W..WW
>     XBX.X       XBX.X       XBX.X       XBXWX
>     WWWWW       W.BWW       BWBW.       BBBWB
>
>  47 BBBB.    34 BBBWW    21 BBWWW    8  W.W.W
>     XBXWX       XBX.X       XBXWX       XBXWX
>     WWW.W       .WBWW       BWB..       BBBWB
>
>  46 BBBB.    33 BBBWW    20 BBWWW    7  W.WWW
>     XBXWX       XBXWX       XBXWX       XBX.X
>     WW.WW       .WB.W       BW.B.       BBBWB
>
>  45 BBBB.    32 BBBWW    19 BBWWW    6  WW.WW
>     XBXWX       XBXWX       XBXWX       XBX.X
>     W.WWW       .W.BW       BW..B       BBBWB
>
>  44 BBBB.    31 BBBWW    18 BBWWW    5  WWW.W
>     X.XWX       XBXWX       XBXWX       XBX.X
>     WBWWW       ..WBW       B.W.B       BBBWB
>
>  43 B.BB.    30 BBBWW    17 BBWWW    4  WWW.W
>     XBXWX       X.XWX       X.XWX       XBXWX
>     WBWWW       .BWBW       BBW.B       BBB.B
>
>  42 BB.B.    29 B.BWW    16 BBWWW    3  WWW.W
>     XBXWX       XBXWX       X.XWX       XBXWX
>     WBWWW       .BWBW       BB.WB       BB.BB
>
>  41 BBB..    28 BB.WW    15 B.WWW    2  WWW.W
>     XBXWX       XBXWX       XBXWX       XBXWX
>     WBWWW       .BWBW       BB.WB       B.BBB
>
>  40 BBBW.    27 BBW.W    14 B.WWW    1  WWWWW
>     XBX.X       XBXWX       XBXWX       XBX.X
>     WBWWW       .BWBW       B.BWB       B.BBB
>
>                                      0  WWWWW
>                                         X.X.X
>                                         BBBBB
> ```

A rearrangement of a few moves allows the solution to be broken up into clear stages, making it much easier to see what is going on.

> ```
>  52 BBBBB
>     X.X.X
>     WWWWW
>
>  Rotate the ring anti-clockwise until spaces are at top right
>
>  43 BB..B
>     XBXWX
>     WBWWW
>
>  Swap top right corner
>
>  39 BBB.W
>     XBX.X
>     WBWWW
>
>  Rotate the ring anti-clockwise until spaces are at bottom left
>
>  33 BBBWW
>     XBXWX
>     W..BW
>
>  Swap bottom left corner
>
>  29 BBBWW
>     X.XWX
>     B.WBW
>
>  Shift the pieces in the ring left to bring spaces to the right bottom
>
>  23 BBWWW
>     XBX.X
>     BWB.W
>
>  Swap bottom right corner
>
>  19 BBWWW
>     XBXWX
>     BW..B
>
>  Rotate the ring anti-clockwise until spaces are at left top
>
>  13 B.WWW
>     X.XWX
>     BBBWB
>
>  Swap top left corner
>
>  9  W..WW
>     XBXWX
>     BBBWB
>
>  Rotate the ring anti-clockwise until all pieces are correct
>
>  0  WWWWW
>     X.X.X
>     BBBBB
> ```

Comment: Great work! Would love to see an animation of this.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Me, too!

Answer (score 9):

> Not the optimal solution of 52 moves as the other answer presents, I managed to get 62 moves by trying to place correct pawns at the four corners first. Once each corner is solved and the remaining black and white pawns are all adjacent, then shifting them is trivial.
>  [image]