# Yin and Yang pawn swap

Tags: sliding-blocks

I was inspired by this great [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120008/exchange-pawns-sliding-block-puzzle).

What is the fewest number of moves needed to exchange the position of black and white pawns in the following grid? Pawns can be moved in four orthogonal directions (no diagonals).

[image]

Comment: Missed opportunity to use [wazirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_(chess))!

Comment: My pleasure to inspire you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was easy to find manually, confirmed optimal via code.

> ```
>  0
>  W W W
>  W - B
>  B B B
>
>  1
>  W W W
>  W B -
>  B B B
>
>  2,3
>  W - W
>  W B W
>  B B B
>
>  4,5,6
>  W B W
>  W B W
>  B B -
>
>  7,8
>  W B -
>  W B W
>  B B W
>
>  9,10,11,12
>  W B B
>  W B W
>  - B W
>
>  13,14
>  - B B
>  W B W
>  W B W
>
>  15,16,17
>  B B B
>  W B W
>  W - W
>
>  18,19
>  B B B
>  - B W
>  W W W
>
>  20
>  B B B
>  B - W
>  W W W
> ```

Comment: Very well done!